# backbone.localStorage, require.js, "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, local-storage

I'm following Uzi Kilon's BackboneJS / RequireJS / backbone.LocalStorage example at http://kilon.org/blog/2012/08/build-backbone-apps-using-requirejs/.

When I `git clone https://github.com/uzikilon/Todos` it works just fine - but it uses older versions of backbone.localstorage. If I replace `lib/backbone.localStorage` with the newer version `http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone-localstorage.js/1.1.0/backbone.localStorage-min`, though, then I get "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" here: https://github.com/uzikilon/Todos/blob/master/js/models/Todo.js#L3 - why? I think this has something to do with the tricky details at http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim or perhaps this: http://blog.mostlystatic.com/2013/01/backbone-localstorage-uncaught.html.

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: "./js/",
  paths: {
    jquery: 'lib/jquery-1.8.2',
    underscore: 'lib/underscore-1.4.2',
    backbone: 'lib/backbone-0.9.2',
//    'backbone.localStorage': 'lib/backbone.localStorage'
    'backbone.localStorage': 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone-localstorage.js/1.1.0/backbone.localStorage-min'

  },
  shim: {
    underscore: {
      exports: "_"
    },
    backbone: {
      deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
      exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    'backbone.localStorage': {
      deps: ['backbone'],
      exports: 'Backbone'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Which line is it firing on in the debugger?  Chrome dev tools show you which line is breaking

Comment: I've updated the example with the line. Basically, RequireJS is not including it properly - why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem lies with the fact that the latest Backbone localStorage is AMD compatible, where as the version in that example is not, hence the shim config.

**The fix**

Remove the `shim` config for backbone.localStorage, you won't be needing it:

```
'backbone.localStorage': {
  deps: ['backbone'],
  exports: 'Backbone'
}
```

Then, in `Todo.js` change the define call from:

```
define(['underscore', 'backbone.localStorage'], function(_, Backbone) {
```

to:

```
define(['underscore', 'backbone', 'backbone.localStorage'], function(_, Backbone) {
```

**Why?**

The shim `exports` config was being used to say 'When I ask for backbone.localStorage, return me Backbone'.

This allowed 'backbone.localStorage' to be used simply as Backbone inside the Todo module.

But now `backbone.localStorage` supports AMD and explicitly returns a value from the `define` call. So the value of `Backbone` in Todo.js is no longer the Backbone library, but is actually a constructor for `Backbone.LocalStorage`

As far as I understand, the `shim` config is ignored for AMD modules, or at least should not be used:

> Only use other "shim" modules as dependencies for shimmed scripts, or
>   AMD libraries that have no dependencies and call define() after they
>   also create a global (like jQuery or lodash). Otherwise, if you use an
>   AMD module as a dependency for a shim config module, after a build,
>   that AMD module may not be evaluated until after the shimmed code in
>   the build executes, and an error will occur. The ultimate fix is to
>   upgrade all the shimmed code to have optional AMD define() calls.

To fix things up the additional dependency needs to be added in Todo.js so that so that the callback parameters match up.

Hopefully that makes sense.